# Problem with parsing strings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, ipad

I am trying to put a line of dialog on each of a series of images.
To match the dialog line with the correct image, I end each line with a forward slash (/) followed by a number to identify the matching image. I then parse each line to get the dialog and then the reference number for the image.
It all works fine except that when I put the dialog line into a textView I get the whole line in the textView instead of the dialog part.
What is confusing is that the console seems to indicate that the parsing of the dialog line has been carried out correctly.

Here are the details of my coding:

```
@interface DialogSequence_1ViewController : UIViewController {

        IBOutlet UIImageView *theImage;
        IBOutlet UITextView *fullDialog;
        IBOutlet UITextView *selectedDialog;
        IBOutlet UIButton *test_1;
        IBOutlet UIButton *test_2;
        IBOutlet UIButton *test_3;
        NSArray *arrayLines;
        IBOutlet UISlider *readingSpeed;
        NSArray *cartoonViews;
        NSMutableString *dialog;
        NSMutableArray *dialogLineSections;
        int lNum;


    }
    @property (retain,nonatomic) UITextView *fullDialog;
    @property (retain,nonatomic) UITextView *selectedDialog;
    @property (retain,nonatomic) UIButton *test_1;
    @property (retain,nonatomic) UIButton *test_2;
    @property (retain,nonatomic) UIButton *test_3;
    @property (retain,nonatomic) NSArray *arrayLines;
    @property (retain,nonatomic) NSMutableString *dialog;
    @property (retain,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *dialogLineSections;
    @property (retain,nonatomic) UIImageView *theImage;
    @property (retain,nonatomic) UISlider *readingSpeed;

    -(IBAction)start:(id)sender;
    -(IBAction)counter:(id)sender;
    -(IBAction)runNextLine:(id)sender;

@end


@implementation DialogSequence_1ViewController
@synthesize fullDialog;
@synthesize selectedDialog;
@synthesize test_1;
@synthesize test_2;
@synthesize test_3;
@synthesize arrayLines;
@synthesize dialog;
@synthesize theImage;
@synthesize readingSpeed;
@synthesize dialogLineSections;


-(IBAction)runNextLine:(id)sender{

    //Get dialog line to display from the arrayLines array
    NSMutableString *dialogLineDetails;
    dialogLineDetails =[arrayLines objectAtIndex:lNum];
    NSLog(@"dialogLineDetails = %@",dialogLineDetails);
    //Parse the dialog line
    dialogLineSections = [dialogLineDetails componentsSeparatedByString: @"/"];
    selectedDialog.text =[dialogLineSections objectAtIndex: 0];
    NSLog(@"Dialog part of line = %@",[dialogLineSections objectAtIndex: 0]);
    NSMutableString *imageBit;
    imageBit = [dialogLineSections objectAtIndex: 1];
    NSLog(@"Image code = %@",imageBit);
    //Select right image
    int im = [imageBit intValue];
    NSLog(@"imageChoiceInteger = %i",im);
//------more code
}
```

I get a warning on the line:

```
dialogLineSections = [dialogLineDetails componentsSeparatedByString: @"/"];
```

warning: incompatible Objective-C types assigning 'struct NSArray *', expected 'struct NSMutableArray *'

I don't quite understand this and have tried to change the types but to no avail.

Would be grateful for some advice here.

Comment: Welcome at SA! A tip: use the dialog-button "Code" to make your code look like code (I edited your q. that way).

Comment: You need to make sure to use the `self.` accessor for class properties e.g. `self.dialogLineSections` because otherwise you have no retention management and the objects in the properties might disappear without warning.

Answer (score 0):

The warning tells you exactly what the problem is. `-componentsSeparatedByString:` returns an immutable instance of `NSArray`, but you're assigning that result to a variable of type `NSMutableArray`. So you need to either change the variable to `NSArray` (in which case you can't modify it) or make a mutable copy of the components array (via `-mutableCopy`, which you *must* balance with `-release` or `-autorelease` to avoid memory leaks.)

Comment: There is no need for a mutableCopy. Simply creating the mutableArray with the contents of the returned static array will suffice. There is no reason to have duplicates of the string objects laying around.

Comment: `-mutableCopy` is a shallow copy; it will not copy the strings, just retain them as part of the new array's initializer.

Comment: True in this case of NSArray but not always. The protocol does not enforce the depth of the copy of an object. If you get in the habit of using `mutableCopy` when you don't actually need a copy, you can find yourself with a deep copy with no warning. Of course, I am paranoid about such things.

Comment: Yes, but, who cares? The same can be said of `-initWithArray:`. Neither one is required to do a shallow copy but you shouldn't need to worry about such things in a well-formed program.

Answer (score 0):

The forward slash character is an escape character so you shouldn't use it as a delimiter. This can lead to random errors in string processing. Pick something else, preferably an arbitrary string like  `!123!`

You are getting the warning because `componentsSeparatedByString:` returns a NSArray instead of an NSMutableArray and you are assigning the static array to a mutable array pointer. Instead use:

```
self.dialogSections=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dialogLineDetails componentsSeparatedByString: @"/"]];
```